# Getting negative values after applying PNG UP predictor to xref stream

Tags: pdf, width, byte, decode

PDF stream decode parameters are as follows.
<>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[]/Index[2573 1 2962 1 2967 2 3004 9]/Info 2573 0 R/Length 58/Prev 1365436/Root 2575 0 R/Size 3013/Type/XRef/W[1 3 0]>>stream
.....

decoded bytes (unsigned int values):
1 20 4294967267 4294967190
1 20 4294967269 74
1 20 4294967284 4294967204
2 0 11 4294967235
1 20 4294967262 24
1 20 4294967262 116
1 20 4294967265 4294967222
1 20 4294967267 60
1 20 4294967267 89
1 20 4294967268 127
1 20 4294967268 4294967196
1 20 4294967270 39
1 20 4294967270 4294967220

not able to interprete it, please help.